# How to insert a file audio with play and stop in pdf LaTex?

Tags: pdftex, media9, audio

I wrote this code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{media9,graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter


    \chapter{Allegati}


        Lezione 1: \includemedia[
        addresource=Phil Collins - You'll Be In My Heart with Lyrics.mp3,
        transparent,
        flashvars={
            source= Phil Collins - You'll Be In My Heart with Lyrics.mp3
            &autoPlay=true
        },
        ]{\includegraphics[height=3ex]{sound-937654_960_720.png}}{APlayer.swf}

\end{document}
```

but i can't stop it during the playing. How can i stop the file audio during its playing?

Comment: [Welcome](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/34551)! What pdf viewer are you using? Did you tried with other pdf viewer? [Adobe reader](https://get.adobe.com/reader/) is often considered a standard to perform tests (even if it is proprietary…).

Comment: @Clément i use Adobe Reader Dc version 10 for mac

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using package `media9` and its `APlayer.swf` app. It offers a number of ways to play/pause/stop playback (see [Pg. 20](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf#page=20) of the documentation):

### Pause:

- press mouse button over the widget and move the mouse out while keeping the button pressed
- press the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar on the keyboard

### Stop: (=pause+rewind)

- press the <kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>Pos1</kbd> key on the keyboard

### Play:

- click on the widget
- press the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar on the keyboard

### Seek:

- arrow keys <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd> (player needs focus; click widget if necessary)

---

The same for the video player `VPlayer.swf`.

Comment: Is it also possible to jump back and forth using by clicking on the time-bar?

Comment: Currently not. But you can use the <-, -> arrow keys.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise that this worked. It takes a long press to notice.

Comment: This is on purpose. Seeking starts slowly, then accelerates. This is to cope with long sound files: seeking precisely around current location, while still being able to skip larger sections easily